# How to Delete all folder with file in server (cpanel) ? where is my Mistake?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This function execute successfully but it doesn't deleted any folder.

```
public function ulink(){
      $path='/home/doman/public_html/projectname/';
      function Delete($path)
        {

     if (is_dir($path) === true)
        {
            $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));

            foreach ($files as $file)
             {
                 Delete(realpath($path) . '/' . $file);
             }

             return rmdir($path);
         }

         else if (is_file($path) === true)
         {
             return unlink($path);
        }

     return false; }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function delfolder($path) {
   $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.','..'));
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      (is_dir("$path/$file")) ? delfolder("$path/$file") : unlink("$path/$file");
    }
    return rmdir($path);
}
```

Comment: I write $path=/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/ and Then write this function but Not works!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for remove all folder and sub folder also.

```
   function viewDir($path) {
    return is_file($path) ?
            @unlink($path) :
            array_map(__FUNCTION__, glob($path.'/*')) == @rmdir($path);
}
$dir=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/xxxx/xxxx";
echo $dir;
viewDir($dir);
```

You can used this function and change `$dir`values for your needs.
it working fine for me..

Comment: Show this message..  Call to undefined function destroy_dir().

Comment: Show this message "/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/projectName/.htaccess Fatal error: Call to undefined function actionCall() in /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/projectName/ line 54."

Comment: Whats up duddies! can u explain you problem ? Can you shown you error details while working in my coding? what kind prblm did you facing ?

Comment: Show this message "/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/projectName/.htaccess Fatal error: Call to undefined function actionCall() in /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/projectName/ line 54. But tnq for your helping..

Comment: @InspireShahin.. i update my answer for your needs.can you tried that code and update me..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
/**
* Remove the directory and its content (all files and subdirectories).
* @param string $dir the directory name
*/
function rmrf($dir) {
    foreach (glob($dir) as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) { 
            rmrf("$file/*");
            rmdir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

for more info: https://www.php.net/glob

Comment: Which parameter included in $dir? only write this function? I try it but no folder deleted!

Comment: you need to call like $path='/home/doman/public_html/projectname/';rmrf($path)

Comment: $path='/home/doman/public_html/projectname/';rmrf($path) I write in this system but  Not Works!